apt upgrade crashed installing python3_3.12.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.
This has happened now on 2 separate servers.
Both servers were up and running for a few days and had multiple successful apt update, apt upgrade sessions.
First server experienced the error yesterday during apt upgrade:
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.12.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
running python pre-rtupdate hooks for python3.12...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.12.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3-stdlib_3.12.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3-stdlib:amd64 (3.12.3-0ubuntu2) over (3.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libsmartcols1_2.39.3-9ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsmartcols1:amd64 (2.39.3-9ubuntu6.1) over (2.39.3-9ubuntu6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.12.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)***

If I try to run apt upgrade after the error I get this:
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.12.3-0ubuntu1) but 3.12.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.12.3-0ubuntu1) but 3.12.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I was unable to fix this and decided to re-install 24.04 from scratch.
Second server experienced the exact same crash this afternoon.
Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this and or prevent it from happening again?

sudo apt autoclean returns:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

sudo apt clean gives no output
sudo apt update shows 23 packages to be updated
sudo apt -f install ends with an error:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 23.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 python3 amd64 3.12.3-0ubuntu2 [23.0 kB]
Fetched 23.0 kB in 0s (184 kB/s)   
(Reading database ... 218408 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.12.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
running python pre-rtupdate hooks for python3.12...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.12.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.12.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

sudo apt install --reinstall python3-minimal libpython3-stdlib python3 ends with an error:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 27.4 kB/50.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 python3-minimal amd64 3.12.3-0ubuntu2 [27.4 kB]
Fetched 27.4 kB in 1s (47.6 kB/s)          
E: Internal Error, No file name for libpython3-stdlib:amd64


Did you run sudo apt update first?

Yes
I run sudo apt update before sudo apt upgrade every time.

I see no mention of phasing when running apt policy python3 python3-minimal

How do I file a bug report?

@MCEComputerService See here and that answer basically links you to here.

@MCEComputerService My bad. I made a mistake. Somehow I downloaded the python3_3.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb package instead of python3_3.12.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb. The control file says 3.12.3-0ubuntu2. See my revised answer.

@MCEComputerService Revised answer posted. See edits if you need to reference the old answer.

First, clean up:
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install

Be sure to review the proposed changes before entering Y (make sure it doesn't want to uninstall stuff you want to keep).
If that doesn't automatically fix the issue, install the dependencies and then install python3:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-minimal libpython3-stdlib python3


EDIT: your error shows the correct pre-depends are already installed or not fully installed so run the following:
sudo dpkg --configure -a

and then:
sudo apt -f install

It is common to need to run dpkg --configure -a when apt -f install or --fix-broken install fails (or generally when apt fails). Often running these two commands over a few times in any particular order will resolve the issue.
If not, then:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall libpython3-stdlib

if it still complains, then run:
cd /tmp
sudo apt download libpython3-stdlib
sudo dpkg --force-confmiss -i ./libpython3-stdlib*.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
cd

and now see if it still complains about python3-minimal when you try to upgrade python3:
sudo apt -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install python3

If it does complain about python3-minimal, then repeat the same process above as for libpython3-stdlib but with python3-minimal instead. Then run sudo apt install --reinstall python3.
If that works, upgrade the other 22 packages:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

You might want to check to see which mirror you're using in /etc/apt/sources.list if you're not using the default mirror, sometimes an alternative mirror might take longer to get all the packages available and this can cause issues similar to the one you've experienced.
Other than that, network issues and sometimes if you kill apt or dpkg during an update, you might experience the issue if one of the pre-depends packages isn't configured (needs sudo dpkg --configure -a).
You can actually check the installation status of a package by running:
dpkg -l | grep python

for example.
Fully installed packages should say ii in the first column (use dpkg -l | grep -v "^ii" to exclude fully installed packages). See this answer for other statuses (like rc means uninstalled but not purged so the configuration files are still in place).

This did not work, see my answer above.

Every time I use 'sudo apt install ' or 'sudo apt upgrade' the process ends in an error.

@MCEComputerService Thanks for the error messages. I have updated the answer.

I have tried all the suggestions given in your updated answer.
The error/bug remains as before.

@MCEComputerService dpkg -l | grep -v "^ii"

@MCEComputerService Also, repeat that process to download the package and use dpkg to install the python3 package. Although, it's best to make sure that the std package isn't one of the two packages not fully installed or installation of python3 will fail as pre-depends aren't met.

@MCEComputerService I doubt you will still see a no file for error on a package that isn't being installed / reinstalled when running sudo apt install --reinstall python3 what error does it give you when you do the manual download and install with  dpkg -i on those packages instead of using apt?

@MCEComputerService Looking at the bug you reported, it shows missing files. The only reason I can think these might not be reinstalled would be that they're considered configuration files, which are supposed to be left alone to preserve user modifications. So we can add an additional option to ask apt or dpkg to replace the missing configuration files: sudo apt -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install python3 python3-minimal libpython3-stdlib and if it complains about missing file for sdtlib then try adding the --force-confmiss options to the dpkg commands in my answer.

I am unable to help with any additional troubleshooting on this as I have installed 24.04.1 on all of the affected machines.
This error occurred for me on two of my servers running 24.04(desktop) and one server running 22.04(desktop) as well as 2 workstations running 22.04(desktop).

@MCEComputerService Honestly though, sudo apt update and then sudo apt -f install and sudo dpkg --configure -a alternated a few times should've fixed the issue and manually downloading the packages, installing manually and trying again should've resolved anything else, dpkg -l | grep -v "^ii" | grep python3 should tell you which packages need to be manually installed.

Clean-up has fixed the problem for me, thanks!
